# Let $(p_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}},\: (a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{C}$. Find a function $f$ such that $f(p_n)=a_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(p_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of different points such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|p_n\right|=\infty$ and let $(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{C}$ be sequence. Find a function $f$ such that $f(p_n)=a_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Remark:** I feel I must use the Runge theorem, but not how to use it.  I would like you to give me some hint to complete the proof correctly.

**Hint:** I got the following hint: $f=\sum f_{n}$, $\quad$ $f_{n}(p_{1})=\cdots=f_{n}(p_{n-1})=0$.  I do not understand this hint.

Comment: I think you want to put restrictions on the type of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am going to use a very special case of the Mittag-Leffler Theorem in here, which is actually proven use Runge's theorem.

Firstly, we know that there exists an entire function $g$ such that $g$ has a zero exactly at the $p_n$'s and such that all the zeros are simple.

Let $c_n = g'(p_n)$. By our hypothesis, $c_n \ne 0$.

By the Mittag-Leffler Theorem, there exists a meromorphic function $h$ such that $h$ has a pole exactly at the $p_n$'s and such that all poles are simple and $\text{Res}(h)_{z= p_n} = \frac{a_n}{c_n}$.

Now take $f = gh$ and you are done.

*Edit*: Indeed, in a deleted neighborhood of $p_n$, you have, $g(z) h(z) = \left( (c_n (z-p_n) + \ldots  \right) \left(\frac{a_n}{c_n (z-p_n)} + \ldots  \right) = a_n + u_1 (z-p_n) + \ldots $.

So, all singularities of $g(z)h(z)$ are removable and it extends to an entire function $f(z)$. 
From the above calculation it follows that $f(p_n) = a_n$.

Comment: Theorems you are using say that $(p_{n})_{n}$ must not have accumulative points. Does this not affect your test?

Comment: Since $\lim |p_n| \to \infty $, it can not have a limit point.

Comment: I do not understand step 3, you could be more specific, i, e, Why $f(p_{n})=a_{n}$?

Comment: just write it down explicitly. See my edit.